# password_verify not working on Raspberry Pi (PHP7)

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I'm currently developing user authentication system for my Raspberry Pi based home automation system.
Unfortunately, I cannot get password_verify() function to work.

When I'm running this code:

```
$hash = '$argon2i$v=19$m=100,t=100,p=2$ZTRqTEVtNmp3aEo4cmJyUQ$bUYczGvH2oo2PN7ROHpay0PUL80alUeSAHWWq2BHHQ4';

if (password_verify('admin', $hash)) 
{
    echo 'password correct';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'password incorrect';
}
```

on my local machine, it works flawlessly and says that the password is correct.
But when I'm running it on my Raspberry Pi server it says that the password is incorrect.

PHP version on Raspberry Pi server: PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1

PHP version on my local machine: PHP 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

Raspberry Pi server: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)

Function that was used to generate hash:

```
function genHash($input)
{
  $options =
  [
    'memory_cost' => 100,
    'time_cost' => 100,
    'threads' => 2,
  ];
  return password_hash($input, PASSWORD_ARGON2I, $options);
}
```

Comment: Install PHP 7.2 on the Pi: http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php

Comment: Or just use the default bcrypt..

Comment: The manual **which should have been your first port of call** says [PASSWORD_ARGON2I Available as of PHP 7.2.0.](http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PASSWORD_ARGON2I` was added in PHP 7.2.0, so anything running PHP < 7.2.0, like your RspberryPi, will not be able to validate hashes created using that algorithm.